# How to to calculate the shortest path in R efficiently?

Tags: r, large-data, shortest-path

I have more than 3500 origins and more than 3500 destinations that are connected by more than 54000 links with 24000 nodes. I am modeling a real street network (Chicago Metropolitan Area) in R using Igraph and CppRouting. The following code is called "all or nothing traffic assignment (AON)" which has to be executed more than 40 times to reach the equilibrium in the network. Now it takes more than 10 minutes for each `AON` execution. It is too much time. I appreciate any suggestion besides parallel computing to reduce the execution time of the following source code:

```
 demand_matrix <- demand_matrix[order(demand_matrix$ORG ,demand_matrix$DEST) ,]
  
  tic()
  for (i in 1:length(unique(demand_matrix$ORG))){
   #I think I have to iterate on every origin
    org <- unique(demand_matrix$ORG)[i]
    destinations <- demand_matrix$DEST[demand_matrix$ORG == org ] 
    demand <- demand_matrix[demand_matrix$ORG == org,2:3]

    #the igraph function is also included here which requires more time to run!
    #destinations <- demand_matrix$DEST[demand_matrix$ORG == org] 
    #sht_path <- unlist(shortest_paths(network_igraph,from =c (org) , to = c(destinations) , mode = c("out"), weights = resolved.Network[[5]]$t0,output = c("epath")),recursive = FALSE)
    #sht_path <- sapply(sht_path , as_ids)
    
#the procedures with cppRouting
    sht_path <- get_multi_paths(network_cpprouting_graph , from = org , to = destinations ,long = TRUE)
    sht_path$end <- c(sht_path$node[2:nrow(sht_path)],0)
    sht_path <-sht_path[sht_path$from != sht_path$node , ]
    sht_path$paste <- paste(sht_path$end , sht_path$node)
    edge_id_node_sequence <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(sht_path$paste , split = " ")))
    sht_path$edge_ids <- get.edge.ids(network_igraph , edge_id_node_sequence)
    ###I changed the sequence of nodes to edge ids in shortest path.
    sht_path$to <- as.integer(sht_path$to) #I just found that "to" is character and changing it to integer would result lower time in left_join function
    sht_path <-left_join(sht_path , demand,by = c("to" = "DEST"))
    V2[sht_path$edge_ids] <- V2[sht_path$edge_ids] + sht_path$TRIPS #adding traffic to each link (that is what is all about, the goal is to calculate each link volume)
    
    }
```

The demand Matrix has more the 4e6 none-zero values and I tried to calculate the shortest path with get_path_pair with all origin-destination Pairs, but it never ended and I restarted my Laptop. I have only 8GB of rams.
I tried to have the shortest paths with only 8e5 pairs each time (divided my matrix to 5 sections) the third section almost never ended.

```
  length_group <- min(nrow(demand_matrix)/4,800000)

  path_pair <- get_path_pair(Graph = test_net , from = demand_matrix$ORG[1:length_group],to = demand_matrix$DEST[1:length_group], long = TRUE)
  path_pair <- rbind(path_pair , get_path_pair(Graph = test_net , from = demand_matrix$ORG[(length_group+1):(2*length_group)],to = demand_matrix$DEST[(length_group+1):(2*length_group)],long = TRUE))
  path_pair <- rbind(path_pair , get_path_pair(Graph = test_net , from = demand_matrix$ORG[((2*length_group)+1):(3*length_group)],to = demand_matrix$DEST[((2*length_group)+1):(3*length_group)],long = TRUE))
  path_pair <- rbind(path_pair , get_path_pair(Graph = test_net , from = demand_matrix$ORG[((3*length_group)+1):(4*length_group)],to = demand_matrix$DEST[((3*length_group)+1):(4*length_group)],long = TRUE))
  path_pair <- rbind(path_pair , get_path_pair(Graph = test_net , from = demand_matrix$ORG[((4*length_group)+1):(5*length_group)],to = demand_matrix$DEST[((4*length_group)+1):(5*length_group)],long = TRUE))
  path_pair <- rbind(path_pair , get_path_pair(Graph = test_net , from = demand_matrix$ORG[((5*length_group)+1):nrow(demand_matrix)],to = demand_matrix$DEST[((5*length_group)+1):nrow(demand_matrix)],long = TRUE))
```

Comment: Djikstra's algorithm might help. You could even store and hash some via-paths and shorten the duration for subsequent searches. But it will take some time, nonetheless. If you want it faster, don't do it in R.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. those packages that I mentioned are using Djikstra's algorithm for their shortest path calculations. The shortest path is one part of the 4-step trip based transportation modeling and I have the rest steps in R. Thus, do you think I can link R with for example a C++ code and this would be faster than what I have now?

Comment: If you already use packages for DA, it's very probable that they, internally, use C code to compute the result. But it's probable that the packages treat each new request individually without any memory. You might get faster if you find a way to store shortest sub-paths in a hashed list. Nevertheless, it will take some time.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of cppRouting package. I confirm that every algorithm is written in C++ and is vectorized. The network size you mention is pretty small, so 10 minutes seems to be very abnormal (see performance on cppRouting github page). Can you explain precisely what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am trying to figure out what I am doing that takes so long. The attached code is what I have. Although the network is not that small (54000 links and 11000 nodes (if remember correct) with 3500 centroids), it is the Chicago Metropolitan Network. But you are right, I tried the get_path_pair for 1e6 rows of demand (I have 12e6 demand matrix which has 8e6  zeros) and it only took 70 seconds. I think I should edit my question here

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `demand_matrix` is all possible combination between origin and destination nodes ? (3500² = 12 250 000)

Since `cppRouting` functions are **vectorized**, why not try :

`get_multi_path(graph, origin, dest, long=TRUE)`

with `origin` and `dest` your origin and destination nodes, with length of ~ 3500.
`get_multi_path` is the equivalent of `get_distance_matrix` function, it use the main property of Dijkstra's algorithm : finding shortest path between an origin node "n" and **all** nodes. So, *full* Dijkstra algorithm is runned N times, with N being origin length.
On the other hand, `get_*_pair` functions run Dijkstra's algorithm with a stopping criterion : when destination node is reached. So you basically increase runtime by a factor of ~1500 (not 3500, because Dijkstra's algorithm is aborted in the last option)

If you have memory issues, splitting all combinations in smaller chunks is the good strategy. However, I suggest you to split origin nodes by 10, then run `get_multi_path` between origin chunk and all destination nodes. At each iteration, you can aggregate the result to have the cumulated flow for each node  of the network.
Finally, try to use `lapply()` and `data.table::rbindlist()` instead of multiple `rbind()` calls.

EDIT : If you want to accumulate traffic on edges, here is a piece of code :

```
library(data.table)

# or are origin nodes (I assume of length 3500)
# dest are destination nodes

chunk_size = 350
test <- lapply(seq(1,3500, chunk_size), function(x){
  print(x)
  res = get_multi_paths(graph, or[x:(x+chunk_size-1)] ,
                          dest,
                          long = TRUE)
  setDT(res)
  # eventually merge demand for each trip (origin-destination)

  # reconstruct edges (by reference using data.table)
  res[,edge_from := c(node[-1], NA),.(from,to)]
  
  # aggregate demand on each edge
  res <- res[!is.na(edge_from),.(traffic = sum(demand)),.(edge_from,node)]
  gc()
  return(res)
})

test <- rbindlist(test)
test <- test[,.(traffic = sum(traffic)),.(edge_from,node)]
```

Of course, you can modify `chunk_size` depending your available memory.